# how to execute a string block from a file

Tags: banner

I have the following command saved in mat.txt file:

```
printf "
       _       ____            __ _
 _ __ (_)_  __/ ___|_ __ __ _ / _| |_
| '_ \| \ \/ / |   | '__/ _` | |_| __|
| | | | |>  <| |___| | | (_| |  _| |_
|_| |_|_/_/\_\\____|_|  \__,_|_|  \__|


"
```

when I execute this file after made it executable using:

```
chmod +x mat.txt
```

It gives me an Error:

[image]

It's saying like command not found, file end reached when searching for ' & syntaxerror.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. You can copy/paste the error as a code block here. This makes the content of the error searchable, and is better for people with visual impairments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> Enclosing  characters  in  double quotes preserves the literal
> value of    all characters within the quotes, with the exception of $,
> `,  ,  and,    when history expansion is enabled, !.

In other words, `" ... "` is not sufficient to protect the unbalanced backtick on line 4 of your text; the shell is interpreting it as the start of a command substitution.

OTOH you can't use single quotes, because your text contains single quotes.

I'd suggest avoiding the issue of quoting altogether by using a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents). You should also use a shebang to make sure your file is interpreted by the intended shell. So:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<'TXT'
       _       ____            __ _
 _ __ (_)_  __/ ___|_ __ __ _ / _| |_
| '_ \| \ \/ / |   | '__/ _` | |_| __|
| | | | |>  <| |___| | | (_| |  _| |_
|_| |_|_/_/\_\\____|_|  \__,_|_|  \__|


TXT
```

then

```
$ ./mat.txt
       _       ____            __ _
 _ __ (_)_  __/ ___|_ __ __ _ / _| |_
| '_ \| \ \/ / |   | '__/ _` | |_| __|
| | | | |>  <| |___| | | (_| |  _| |_
|_| |_|_/_/\_\\____|_|  \__,_|_|  \__|
```

Comment: It looks like the first line needs to be indented by 7 spaces :)

Comment: @Freddy thanks I hadn't noticed that

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver . That helped.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't ask for a specific interpreter in your question. Therefore, **Python**(*which allows assigning a multi-line string to a variable using triple quotes be it single `''' ... '''` or double `""" ... """`*)  might be an option like so:

```py
#!/bin/python3

a = '''
       _       ____            __ _
 _ __ (_)_  __/ ___|_ __ __ _ / _| |_
| '_ \| \ \/ / |   | '__/ _` | |_| __|
| | | | |>  <| |___| | | (_| |  _| |_
|_| |_|_/_/\_\\____|_|  \__,_|_|  \__|
'''

print(a)
```

Which executes like so:

```bash
$ ./mat.txt 

       _       ____            __ _
 _ __ (_)_  __/ ___|_ __ __ _ / _| |_
| '_ \| \ \/ / |   | '__/ _` | |_| __|
| | | | |>  <| |___| | | (_| |  _| |_
|_| |_|_/_/\_\____|_|  \__,_|_|  \__|
```